# Checking 1 variable for fulfilling modulus 11 in R

Tags: r

I wish to check whether 2500 social security numbers are fulfilling the modulus 11, by predicting the last digit (the 10th) from the first 9 digits. All 10 digits are in one column written like this:

- XXXXXX-XXXX

Where the first six digits are the date of birth (DDMMYY) and the last 4 are given at birth.

---

The modulus 11 algorithm for the social security number: 111111-111X

- 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
- x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
- 4  3  2  7  6  5  4  3  2
- =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =  =
- 4 + 3 +2 +7 +6 +5 +4 +3 +2 = 36
- 36 = ( 3 x 11 ) + 3
- 11 - 3 = 8

Conclusion: the last digit would be 8.

---

Until now I have this code (which will not handle each digit seperately):

```
CPR$mod11 <- 11 - substr(CPR$CPR,1,1)*4 + substr(CPR$CPR,2,2)*3 +
substr(CPR$CPR,3,3)*2 + substr(CPR$CPR,4,4)*7 + substr(CPR$CPR,5,5)*6 + 
substr(CPR$CPR,6,6)*5 + substr(CPR$CPR,7,7)*4 + 
substr(CPR$CPR,8,8)*3 + substr(CPR$CPR,9,9)*2 %% 11)
```

What I want is that R use the first 9 numbers separately, even though all 10 digits are in one column, and the call back whether the 10th digit is fulfilling modulus 11 or not.

I hope this makes sense - I'm a noob at R, so I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
check.CPR<- function(x){
  x <- sub("-", "", x) # remove -
  x <- substr(x, 1,10)

  # Calculate digit sum
  x <- as.integer(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])
  num <- as.integer(strsplit("4327654321", "")[[1]])
  digit_sum <- sum(x*num)

  # Check last digit
  0 == (digit_sum %% 11)   
}
```

The problem with the original function posted by Floo0 was that if the modulus equaled 0 it would come out as false. With this it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Some one liners, possibly to insert into a `dplyr` mutate step:

#### Nesting function, explicit infixes

```
11 - sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub('-','',SN),'')))[1:9] * as.numeric(unlist(strsplit('432765432', '')))) %% 11 == substr(cf, 10, 10)
```

#### Fully nested

```
'=='('%%'('-'(11,sum('*'(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub('-','',SN),'')))[1:9],as.numeric(unlist(strsplit('432765432', '')))))),11),substr(cf, 11, 11))
```

#### Deep piping

```
SN %>% 
    gsub(pat = '-', r = '') %>% 
    strsplit('') %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    as.numeric %>% 
    .[1:9] %>% 
    '*'(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit('432765432', '')))) %>%  
    sum %>%  
    '%%'(11) %>% 
    '-'(11, .)  %>% 
    '=='(substr(cf, 11,11))
```

Not that they are particularly useful, better, or even understandable. Just a fun answer.

---

To apply this to all the `SN`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
    mutate(valid = 11 - sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub('-','',SN),'')))[1:9] * as.numeric(unlist(strsplit('432765432', '')))) %% 11 == substr(cf, 10, 10))
```

Where `mydf` is your data and `SN` is your SecurityNumber column